# Is there a maximum size for input and output stream in external accessory framework?

Tags: external-accessory

Is there a maximum size for input and output stream in external accessory framework? If I am sending something big across, do I need to chunk it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to send the data over Bluetooth or wired? In case of bluetooth, it depends on the MTU of the RFCOMM channel you are connecting over. I am not sure with wired connection.

Comment: Trying to send over regular USB cable.

Comment: I haven't tried though. Maybe you can look up in "Firmware Specification" if you're in MFi program. In bluetooth, the iOS will try to pack as much data in a packet of MTU size. This MTU is defined during IDPS, if you don't set it, the iOS will default to 1024bytes. Read the specification again.